# How to differentiate form submit with method="get" and link request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to differentiate form submit with method="get" and link request in asp net core controller action ?

```
<form method="get" asp-action="amethod">
<input type="text" name="q"/>
</form>
```

and

```
<a asp-action="amethod" asp-route-q="">Q?</a>
```

Now as a solution I set a cookie on submit event of the form and remove it on server . .. .

Comment: You could possibly add a querystring parameter to one or both requests, but what I'm wondering most is why you would do that? If both serve a different purpose, then give them both a different endpoint. Either with a POST or a different url

Comment: I can only think that the easiest way is to add a unique input or parameter to the form and check it in the action.

Comment: I have a paged data table with "next", "prev" page and a filtering form. Form submit with get method places all values in querystring (this saves state, when you copy/paste the url). "next" / "prev" are links to the same action method as the form action, to only go next/prev page. If user submits a new filtering form data, current page resets to 1.

Comment: If I understand, you basically want the page to reset to 1 when someone submits the form?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes. And the Url also reflect the same. Accessing the Request.Form throws exception "by design" if the values where read - I think the model binder dose that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the page number when the user submits the form, *then don't send the page number* with the rest of the form data. In other words, you presumably have a hidden field containing the page number in your form. Just remove that. It will no longer be part of the URL and assuming you're correctly defaulting the page to 1, you'll be at page 1, just simply because it will have been provided no value.

Comment: If I use the links the hidden input page will not be in the url. Only on form submit.

Comment: I don't understand. Your paging links *obviously* have the page param in those URLs, since that's how you switch pages. Even if they're just "next" and "prev", On form submit, you don't need an input for the page, because page is not a factor for that. Any time that's submitted, page restarts at 1, so just remove the input.

Comment: "Your paging links obviously have the page param in those URLs" yes I tried removing them because I get the page param from the last click on the next / prev links on form submit. from query-string ..

Comment: In the end I changed my route template and a page parameter is visible then added a hidden input with the same name "page", on submit I reset it to 0. The links also have the same parameter page + 1 -1. It is strange if there is a custom route template .. Otherwise the parameters get merged if you submit the form the field value overrides the query param if you navigate on link only then the value in the link is used and the rest of the url remains.